# Show a given city on a given map using Open Street Maps

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm making a website and I would like to be able to show a location a user has entered on an open street map for example a user might enter "London" in to the input field then it shows them that location on the map.

This is the current html file I've got for it at the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TESTING</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body onload="showLocation();">
    <input type="text" id="locInput">
    <button onclick="showLocation();">Find the location!</button>
    <div id="osm-map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showLocation() {
            var element = document.getElementById('osm-map');
            var location = document.getElementById('locInput').value;
            console.log(location);

            element.style = 'height:500px; width:500px;';

            var map = L.map(element);
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);

            var target = L.latLng('40.7128', '-74.00601');
            map.setView(target, 10);

            L.marker(target).addTo(map);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment which plugin would you recommend?

Comment: I do not recommend any in particular; each has its advantages and disadvantages. You should conduct your own research to see what fits your requisites and circumstances the best.